Help me identify a thriller
One of the main characters gets stabbed in the stomach by a single man in a public square meeting at night. There is conversation before the stabbing. It is business related and the stabber is not a low level criminal. After that he barely manages to return to the apartment with significant blood loss. Someone greets him in the apartment. I think that the person who greets him is his brother and the stabbed character is played by Michael Douglas (or his brother is stabbed, anyways one of the main characters is Douglas). This happened near the end of the movie.
There is also a scene where Douglas visits him in his dirty apartment and they drink some alcohol, possibly fancy and there are no clean glasses, but they still use dirty glasses.
For extra detail, earlier in the movie there is a dinner scene in a restaurant where Douglas says to his brother (?) that the woman he is seeing is lying to him and it is apparent. The brother (?) gets mad at him even though he is obviously right about the woman.
Since Michael Douglas is character it is US movie spoken in U.S. English. Douglas is not old like he is today, but also not young. I think he still had some or most hair color. The woman the brother(?) is with is some kind of foreign exchange student or something like that and they fall in love. But it is a setup to gain something from him. Possibly US citizenship, but maybe something else. It is also possible Douglas is wealthy, but at least comfortable.
I searched Douglas imdb page with his movies but I still couldn't find it. It's possible I overlooked something.

When was it released?

You might want to provide a more descriptive question title.

I just remembered that I mixed it up with Marathon Man (1976). 
No wonder I couldn't find it. You just replace Douglas with Roy Scheider and we have a solution. So I guess this is solved.

As the question and answer have 5 downvotes combined, you might as well delete them both 1) to regain your rep 2) they aren't particularly good to keep on the site.
